# (setup.py) list of the installed files

Tags: python, installation

I'm using a [setup.py](https://github.com/suizokukan/dchars/blob/master/setup.py) file for my library ([DChars](https://github.com/suizokukan/dchars)); the installation is ok :

```
sudo python setup.py install --record myfiles.txt
```

Uninstall is also easy :

```
cat files.txt | xargs rm -rf
```

Here's my question : how can I get the 'myfiles.txt' file ( = the list of all files installed, with the real path to them, not simply the files' names) without launching the installation ?

Thanks !

Comment: usually `setup.py` keeps a list of this files in the egg-info directory of the installed package. using `pip`, `pip show -f packagename` should show you these files, and `pip uninstall packagename` should make uninstalling easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sadly, even though there's a `--dry-run` option, it does not affect the `install` command. The only solution I found to get around that problem is to do:

```
mkdir tmpdst
python setup.py install --root tmpdst --record myfiles.txt
rm -rf tmpdst
```

it will install all the files in the local `tmpdst` directory, and print all path to the files rooted on that directory. Then you can get rid of the `tmpdst` directory.

Comment: Thank you zmo but I'm looking specifically to the path where the files will be installed (/usr/local/... and so on): with your solution I will only know the files' names, the path being "tmpdst/".

Comment: no, the path is not `tmpdst`, it will be where in `tmpdst` they are installed. Then you can prepend to those paths where you want/expect them to get in, whether it is `/usr`, `/usr/local`...